# Form action not accepting get variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form element that I change the action of with the following code

HTML:

```html
<form action='#' id='EventsBlockForm'>
    <select id='artikler' onchange='getUrl(this)'>
        <option disabled selected>-- Velg artikkel</option>
        <option value='/?id=198405547&Article=1'>Article 1</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Go to article</button>
<form>
```

JS:

```js
function getUrl(input) {
    let form = document.getElementById("EventsBlockForm");
    form.action = input.value;
}
```

The javascript works and it does change the action to the correct value, however when I click the submit button it sends me to `/?id=198405547` instead of sending me to `/?id=198405547&Article=1`. Is there a way to get the second GET variable in the action. This works fine if I use a `a` elemenent instead of the button.

Comment: You can use [input type="hidden"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) for sending the queries together when the form is submitted.
In your case, it would be <input type="hidden" name="Article" value="1">
You can also do the same for the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("artikler").addEventListener("change",function() {
    location = "/?"+this.value
  })
})
```

```html
<form action='#' id='EventsBlockForm'>
    <select id='artikler'>
        <option disabled selected>-- Velg artikkel</option>
        <option value='id=198405547&Article=1'>Article 1</option>
    </select>
<form>
```

or

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("EventsBlockForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = document.getElementById("artikler").value;
    if (val) location = "/?"+val;
  })
})
```

```html
<form action='#' id='EventsBlockForm'>
    <select id='artikler'>
        <option disabled selected>-- Velg artikkel</option>
        <option value='id=198405547&Article=1'>Article 1</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Go to article</button>
<form>
```